# Error: Colab notebook accessing Google Drive image

Tags: keras, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import images from my Google Drive to Colab notebook but facing error. Earlier, same code was working.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/', force_remount=True)
content_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname='Amrita.jpeg', origin='/content/gdrive/My Drive/Amrita.jpeg')
style_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname='Frida.jpeg', origin='/content/gdrive/My Drive/Frida.jpeg')
```

Error is as follows:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Amrita.jpeg'
```

The images are in my Google Drive root folder.

Comment: try with the path /content/drive/...

Comment: There is no need to use get_file here, this function takes URLs, not paths.

Comment: I need to later use it @Dr.Snoopy in: 

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(content_image, 'Content Image')

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Using the URL from Google Drive solved the issue, but now the following fails:

     content_image = load_img(content_path)
    



/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)



InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required. [Op:DecodeImage]

Comment: Again, you don't need to use get_file for local files, just pass your path directly to load_image.

Comment: content_image = load_img('https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fy13tZYtE5yKYy0I-a5uqq15KatUG4VVVW/view?usp=sharing')

Another error:
UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'https' not implemented (file: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fy13tZYtE5yKYuqq15KatUG4W/view?usp=sharing') [Op:ReadFile]

Comment: did you ever solve this?  I'm having exact same problem.  How do you pass a google drive (external link) to load_img??